# How does OKCupid, Reddit handle user profile routing with react router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to set up a similar structure, where /profile takes you to your profile and allows you to edit your info. /profile/:userId will take you to someone else's profile, and allow you to send messages but not edit (obviously). I am thinking something similar to this logic:

```
<Route path='profile'> 
  <IndexRoute component={requireAuth(Profile)} />
  <Route path=':userId' component={requireAuth(Profile)} />
</Route>
```

and in the `Profile` component, do something like

```
if (this.props.params.userId !== this.props.currentUser.id) 
  <SendMessage toUser={this.props.params.userId} />
```

This gets cumbersome as there will be a ton of validation checks for pretty much every element on the page whether it's the current user or another profile. Is there a 'correct' way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The components for your own profile page (/profile) and the others page (/profile/:userId) should be different components (with maybe similar markup). The component for /profile for example need not have the `<SendMessage/>` etc.

```
<Route path='profile' onEnter={requireAuth}> 
  <IndexRoute component={ProfileSelfComponent} />
  <Route path=':userId' component={ProfileOtherComponent} />
</Route>
```

The `requireAuth` will handle whether the user is logged in etc.

The only thing you want is that when a user tries to navigate to his own /profile/:profileId it routes back to his own profile

This can be done by adding something like this to the `ProfileOtherComponent`

```
componentWillMount(){
    if (this.props.params.userId === this.props.currentUser.id) 
         browserHistory.push('/profile')
}
```

Comment: great, thanks! exactly what I was looking for. I didn't want to repeat most of the markup, but it seems like I will have to.

Comment: Yeah repeating the markup is the convention and far more efficient as the markup is already there and you don't have to keep doing all those validation checks on every single profile page.